# How to separate digits in text field with grouped thousands

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Sorry for my not good english. I just bought a Wordpress theme. But I can't format the number with grouped thousands in the text filed in this php file.

I don't know much about PHP. Just a newbie

```php
echo '<tr style="display:none" class="step_1">';
echo '  <th scope="row" valign="top">'.esc_html__('Price', 'bookyourtravel').
' <span class="per_person" '.(!$is_price_per_group ? '' : 'style="display:none"').
'>'.esc_html__('per adult', 'bookyourtravel').
'</span> <span class="per_group" '.($is_price_per_group ? '' : 'style="display:none"').
'>'.esc_html__('per group', 'bookyourtravel').
'</span> *</th>';
echo '  <td><input type="text" name="price_regular" id="price_regular" value="'.esc_attr($price_regular).
'" /></td>';
echo '</tr>';

echo '<tr style="display:none" class="per_person step_1">';
echo '  <th scope="row" valign="top">'.esc_html__('Price per child', 'bookyourtravel').
' *</th>';
echo '  <td><input type="text" name="price_child" id="price_child" value="'.esc_attr($price_child).
'" /></td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

I want to formart a digit from example 1000000 to 1,000,000

Answer (score 0):

Try `number_format()` function. For example:

```
$number = 1000000;
echo format_number($number);
```

For some more details see: https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/number_format.php

Comment: Thanks for your kindly support. I did it !